# Oldest Record discrepancy?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I was trying to determine the oldest record in a table and am having conflicting results.

**Scenario 1**

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Ens_Util.Log ORDER BY TimeLogged ASC`

`SELECT TOP 10 text, TimeLogged, TraceCat, Type FROM Ens_Util.Log ORDER BY TimeLogged ASC`

```
Text                            TimeLogged          TraceCat    Type
Email sent via mailserv:25      2016-05-08 01:00:01 (null)      4
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:01:13 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:04:39 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:04:53 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:05:22 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:05:45 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:05:58 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:05:58 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:06:08 (null)      2
[Requested record not found]    2016-05-08 01:06:15 (null)      2
```

**Scenario 2a**

`SELECT TOP 10 TimeLogged FROM Ens_Util.Log ORDER BY TimeLogged ASC`

```
TimeLogged
2015-10-10 16:30:46
2015-10-10 21:15:07
2015-10-11 22:08:18
2015-10-12 21:57:00
2015-10-13 21:39:27
2015-10-14 23:40:15
2015-10-15 23:28:10
2015-10-16 23:36:52
2015-10-17 23:10:04
2015-10-18 22:32:49
```

**Scenario 2b**

`SELECT MIN(TimeLogged) FROM Ens_Util.Log`

`2015-10-10 16:30:46`

**Question**

What is happening here?  Why the discrepancy?  What is the date of the oldest record?  `2016-05-08` or `2015-10-10`?

Comment: I would re-index and rebuild the stats then try it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More looks like your indices are incorrect, while in the different queries uses different indices. Just call this two commands, to purge all index, and rebuild it again, it may take a long time depends on how many logs you have.

```
do ##class(Ens.Util.Log).%PurgeIndices()
do ##class(Ens.Util.Log).%BuildIndices()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to do this but I have put in a request to our host.  I'll update with the outcome.

Comment: If you have an access, you may try to do it through [System Portal management](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_persother#GOBJ_persother_rls_existrbld)

Comment: "We can confirm what you have reported on that instance. We are investigating the cause of 
this at this time and will update you by tomorrow with our findings."

Comment: "We have decided to rebuild the indices for the Ens_Util.Log table and it has cleared up the index entries pointing to non-existing log messages. "

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would try:

- checked that TimeLogged is really a datatime field
- try to cast as string and sort (sometime implicit casts confuse sorting)
- try to cast as date

worst case scenario :

try to order by Year(TimeLogged), Month(TimeLogged), Day(TimeLogged), Hour(TimeLogged), Minute(TimeLogged), Second(TimeLogged)

also, just in case :

try to select Year(TimeLogged), Month(TimeLogged), Day(TimeLogged), Hour(TimeLogged), Minute(TimeLogged), Second(TimeLogged)
to see if you can extract correct values from TimeLogged